# Reading and writing from xls and xlsx excel file in java using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am writing a program which needs to read and write from excel files, irrespective of the format(xls or xlsx).

I am aware of the Apache POI, but it seems it has different classes to handle xls file(HSSF) and xlsx(XSSF) files.

Anyone aware of how I might achieve what I am trying to do here.
(Ideas for using an API other than POI are also welcome).

Comment: Have you tried to follow the tutorial in the Apache website? It's not so hard!Write some code by yourself then ask!

Comment: I did try..but as mentioned in my question the API uses different classes to handle different types. See my comment below.

Comment: Well,then I think you have to build your own interface to hide the underline implementation detail, the Abstract Factory Pattern for example.

Comment: @Harry.Chan seems I might end up..doing just that ...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's very easy, just use the common [SpreadSheet interfaces](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#user_api)

Your code would look something like:

```
 Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("myFile.xls")); // Or .xlsx
 Sheet s = wb.getSheet(0);
 Row r1 = s.getRow(0);
 r1.createCell(4).setCellValue(4.5);
 r1.createCell(5).setCellValue("Hello");

 FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("newFile.xls"); // Or .xlsx
 wb.write(out);
 out.close();
```

You can read, write, edit etc an existing file, both .xls and .xlsx, with exactly the same code as long as you use the common interfaces

Answer (score 2):

Why not detect the file type from extension and use the appropriate Apache POI class for processing? I doubt there's an absolutely universal out-of-the-box solution for your situation.

Comment: A quick glance at Apache POI documentation shows, that both HSSF and XSSF seem to implement same interfaces - HSSFWorkbook and XSSFWorkbook for example both have a Workbook interface to work with.

You just need to detect the type, instantiate the correct type and the rest of the code should be doable through the general interface.

Comment: POI provides a class for detecting the type and building the correct object for you - `WorkbookFactory` - see my answer for details