# How to generate URL of Oracle EBS concurrent program generated file (like .pdf) from API?

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-generation, oracle-ebs

I am Android developer. Recently I am working on PDF generation project. We use Oracle EBS. In this system there is an concurrent program that generate PDF of PF ledger. We can get the PDF by running concurrent program in Oracle Apps. My task is to generate the same PDF from Android app.

Now I want to develop an API that will return a URL of concurrent program generated PDF file.

Is it possible in such way that? If possible, please, give me guideline to do the work.

Comment: The database procedure fnd_webfile.get_url mentioned in [Generate the URL of a Remote File using PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41426681/20324967) might work for you.