# Produce a fixed-width flat format output file from a SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need help producing fixed width file where every row is the same length. I know I have to cast each field as a fixed length character field. The size of the field should be the maximum size of the field in the source table.However, just could not produce the file using below query -

```
    Select cast(x.account_id as char(10)) ||
           cast(birth_month as char(2)) ||
           cast(birth_year as char(4))|| 
           TO_CHAR(LastVisittDate,'yyyymmdd') ||'    '||
           max(case when email_Rank = 1 then cast(email_address as char(100)) else null end) ||chr(13) as ConstitRow

 from INTERS XR
               inner join INTERS_REL RX on XR.account_id = RX.account_id and RX.sts <> 'D'

       where 
               RX.account_id in (deleted - long list of account IDs)
```

Comment: is PL/SQL an option for you? or just plain SQL?

Comment: Yes it is - Thanks

Comment: Isn't every row the same length just using sqlplus? Am i missing something?

Comment: i checked your query and you seem to be missing the Table Names. Please update your Query from the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create an Excel File (.xlsx) using PL/SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41299024/create-an-excel-file-xlsx-using-pl-sql)

Comment: I have updated the query by adding source table

Comment: The query works fine, but it just produces a  wrong format file

Comment: what format file are you producing? are you producing a file from SQL Developer or SQL*Plus?

Answer (score 0):

You are casting your column values to `char(n)`, which will pad shorter strings and numbers (implicitly converted to strings) to *n* chars, and truncate longer values. (This is better than using `varchar2(n)`, which would error with longer numbers and wouldn't make any difference to shorter strings).

You will have a problem with nulls though, as `cast(null as char(n))` - or anything else - is still null, rather than *n* spaces as you might expect. That may be a problem for any of your columns, but particularly for your case expressions.

If any columns can be null you can use `nvl` or `coalesce` to treat them as a single space instead, and the cast will then pad those too:

```
cast(coalesce(First_name, ' ') as char(20))
```

Rather than casting, you could also use `rpad()`:

```
rpad(coalesce(First_name, ' '), 20, ' ')
```

For the case expressions you can make the `else` clause evaluate to a single space instead of null, but you also need to apply the cast to the overall case expression, not have it within one `when` branch; so instead of this:

```
max(case when email_Rank = 1 then cast(email_address as char(100)) else null end)
```

you would do:

```
cast(max(case when email_Rank = 1 then email_address else ' ' end) as char(100))
```

or if you prefer:

```
cast(coalesce(max(case when email_Rank = 1 then email_address end), ' ') as char(100))
```

---

Your client may have been right-padding the overall string to the same length anyway (SQL*Plus will do that if you have `set trimout off`, or if spooling `set trimspool off`; which might be what BobC was referring to), but that doesn't really help if what you're really trying to create is fixed length *fields*, which cumulatively would give you a fixed length record as well - and if you didn't have fixed length fields it would impossible to interpret the data anyway.

Comment: Hi Alex - Thanks for the help. I got everything done except for
cast(birth_day as char(2))||
and
TO_CHAR(LastGiftDate,'yyyymmdd')
I am getting "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got CHAR"

Comment: @AmeerB. - what data types are those two columns?

Answer (score -1):

I had the similar problem before. There's a package named [as_xlsx](https://technology.amis.nl/2011/02/19/create-an-excel-file-with-plsql/) by Anton Scheffer, and it addressed my problem. Check out question about this: [Create an Excel File (.xlsx) using PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41299024/create-an-excel-file-xlsx-using-pl-sql/41356022#41356022). Hope this helps you out.

Comment: @AmeerB. I'll repeat my question. Do you not get a fixed format by default from sqlplus?