# SYS_REFCURSOR not working when using Explicit Cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

We have an existing package that inserts data into a Table stored in a remote Database (SQL Server). Below is the summary of the package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE XXMyPackage
AS

  PROCEDURE GiveMyCursor;

END XXMyPackage;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY XXMyPackage
AS

  PROCEDURE GiveMyCursor IS

    cursor cursor_1 is
    SELECT 'really long query with a lot of joined tables'  column1
        ,  'this is an existing code'                       column2
        ,  'i cannot modify this'                           column3
    from   dual;

  BEGIN

    for cursor_x in cursor_1 loop
        sql_stmt := 'insert into some_remote_table (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5)'||
        'values (:1,    0,    :2,    :3,    0) ';
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt
        USING trim(cursor_x.column1),
        trim(cursor_x.column2),
        trim(cursor_x.column3);
        l_count := get_records_for_insert%rowcount;
    end loop;

  END GiveMyCursor;

END XXMyPackage;
/
```

I am tasked to add functionality to this package by dumping its contents into an `XLSX` file in a directory after the insertion.
In addition, I should make very minimal modifications to existing code, and make the code as short as possible.
I was able to do this with the below modifications (note the lines with the "added" comments:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE XXMyPackage
AS

  TYPE refMyCursor IS REF CURSOR RETURN curMyCursor%ROWTYPE;    -- added
  TYPE typMyCursor IS TABLE OF curMyCursor%ROWTYPE;             -- added

  PROCEDURE GiveMyCursor;

END XXMyPackage;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY XXMyPackage
AS

  PROCEDURE GiveMyCursor IS

    pCursor         SYS_REFCURSOR;                                      -- added
    l_directory     DBA_DIRECTORIES.DIRECTORY_NAME%TYPE := 'DATA_DIR';  -- added
    l_filename      VARCHAR2(250) := 'SAMPLE_FILENAME';                 -- added

    cursor cursor_1 is
    SELECT 'really long query with a lot of joined tables'  column1
        ,  'this is an existing code'                       column2
        ,  'i cannot modify this'                           column3
    from   dual;

  BEGIN

    for cursor_x in cursor_1 loop
        sql_stmt := 'insert into some_remote_table (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5)'||
        'values (:1,    0,    :2,    :3,    0) ';
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt
        USING trim(cursor_x.column1),
        trim(cursor_x.column2),
        trim(cursor_x.column3);
        l_count := get_records_for_insert%rowcount;
    end loop;

    /* **************** Start of added Code  **************** */
    -- cursor query was re-used
    OPEN pCursor FOR 
    SELECT 'really long query with a lot of joined tables'  column1
        ,  'this is an existing code'                       column2
        ,  'i cannot modify this'                           column3
    from   dual;

    l_filename := l_filename||'_'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DDMMYYYYHHMISS')||'.xlsx';

    -- dumps the query results into an xlsx file
    as_xlsx.query2sheet( p_cur          => pCursor      -- Uses Sys_RefCursor
                       , p_sheetname    => l_filename   -- This is where we assign the Sheet Names
                       , p_directory    => l_directory  -- Saves it into the directory
                       , p_filename     => l_filename   -- The filename of the xlsx file
                       );                       

    /* **************** End of added Code **************** */

  END GiveMyCursor;

END XXMyPackage;
/
```

Note: The package `as_xlsx` was taken from another SO post ([Create an Excel File (.xlsx) using PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41299024/create-an-excel-file-xlsx-using-pl-sql))

I've confirmed that the modified package works and can see the file in the directory when I run `XXMyPackage.GiveMyCursor` in an anonymous block. However, `cursor_1` is extremely long and was re-used in opening the `SYS_REFCURSOR` `pCursor`. I attempted to make this shorter my further modifying the code to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE XXMyPackage
AS
    /* **************** Start of added Code **************** */
    cursor cursor_1 is
    SELECT 'really long query with a lot of joined tables'  column1
        ,  'this is an existing code'                       column2
        ,  'i cannot modify this'                           column3
    from   dual;    

    TYPE typMyCursor IS TABLE OF cursor_1%ROWTYPE;      
    /* **************** End of added Code **************** */

    PROCEDURE GiveMyCursor;

END XXMyPackage;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY XXMyPackage
AS

  PROCEDURE GiveMyCursor IS

    tabMyCursor     typMyCursor;                                        -- added        
    pCursor         SYS_REFCURSOR;                                      -- added
    l_directory     DBA_DIRECTORIES.DIRECTORY_NAME%TYPE := 'DATA_DIR';  -- added
    l_filename      VARCHAR2(250) := 'SAMPLE_FILENAME';                 -- added

  BEGIN

    for cursor_x in cursor_1 loop
        sql_stmt := 'insert into some_remote_table (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5)'||
        'values (:1,    0,    :2,    :3,    0) ';
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt
        USING trim(cursor_x.column1),
        trim(cursor_x.column2),
        trim(cursor_x.column3);
        l_count := get_records_for_insert%rowcount;
    end loop;

    /* **************** Start of added Code **************** */
    OPEN cursor_1;
    FETCH cursor_1 BULK COLLECT INTO tabMyCursor;  
    CLOSE cursor_1;

    OPEN pCursor FOR
    SELECT  *
    FROM    TABLE(tabMyCursor);

    l_filename := l_filename||'_'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DDMMYYYYHHMISS')||'.xlsx';

    -- dumps the query results into an xlsx file
    as_xlsx.query2sheet( p_cur          => pCursor      -- Uses Sys_RefCursor
                       , p_sheetname    => l_filename   -- This is where we assign the Sheet Names
                       , p_directory    => l_directory  -- Saves it into the directory
                       , p_filename     => l_filename   -- The filename of the xlsx file
                       );                       

    /* **************** End of added Code **************** */

  END GiveMyCursor;

END XXMyPackage;
/
```

However, when I do this, I get the error `No more data to read from socket` some seconds after running `XXMyPackage.GiveMyCursor` in an anonymous block. What could be the cause of this error?

Database Version:

```
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE   12.1.0.2.0  Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
```

Comment: `No more data to read from socket` is a message indicating some Oracle process has crashed, probably with ORA-600 or ORA-7445 error stack. There should be more information in the Alert log and/or a trace file. However, if I were a betting man I would look at your BULK COLLECT statement. How many rows does `cursor1` return? How many columns? `tabMyCursor` is stored in **session memory** so if the result set  is too big you may be breaching the PGA limit.

Comment: @APC the query returns 2055 rows.

Comment: @APC, it's three columns and with a maximum length of 52. Can you kindly point me to any article that would let me know where to find the Alert Log and/or generate a trace file from `SQL Developer`?

Comment: @APC, our Alert Log is located in `/u02/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/DEV/dbhome_1/rdbms/log`. Unfortunately, i don't see any new entries or `.trc` files whenever i try to re-create the issue. :(

Comment: And there are no trace files either? It could also be a network or TNS Names issue.. However, there's nothing further I can add. You need to take this up with Oracle Support (if you have a Support contract).

Comment: I'll check on the trace files as well. but in terms of logic and syntax, the code is correct, right? @APC