# How to run oracle 12c report in excel

Tags: oracle, export-to-excel, oracle12c, oraclereports

want to run oracle 12 c report in excel

i want to run oracle 12 c report to excel,but not finding the way,i have posted code below please help me

```
Declare
   pl_id paramlist;
   v_rep_server varchar2(100);
 v_path varchar2(100);

 v_rep varchar2(100);

begin

 v_rep := 'SAMPLE_DETAIL_f.rdf';

 v_rep_server := pckg_erp.f_get_report_server_name(NULL,'192.168.0.231',null,null,null);
 v_path := pckg_erp.f_get_object_path(NULL ,v_rep,'R',null,35,'192.168.0.231',null,null,null); 

 WEB_REPORT.SETREPORTSSERVER(v_rep_server);
   WEB_REPORT.setDesformat('xls');

   pl_id:=get_parameter_list('temp');

   if not id_null(pl_id) then
       destroy_parameter_list(pl_id);
   end if;

   pl_id := Create_Parameter_List('temp'); 

   add_parameter(pl_id,'PARAMFORM',text_parameter,'NO');
   add_parameter (pl_id,'DESTYPE',TEXT_PARAMETER,'LOCALFILE');
   add_parameter (pl_id,'DESFORMAT',TEXT_PARAMETER,'ENHANSEDSPREADSHEET');
   add_parameter(pl_id,'MAXIMIZE',text_parameter,'YES');   
WEB_REPORT.RUN_REPORT(reports,v_path||v_rep,synchronous,runtime,filesystem,pl_id,null);

end;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create an Excel File (.xlsx) using PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41299024/create-an-excel-file-xlsx-using-pl-sql)

Comment: What are `web_report`, `pckg_erp`, `destroy_parameter_list` etc? I've never heard of them. Do you need to use those, or Oracle Reports (which is tagged), or a generic PL/SQL solution, or else have Excel connect to the database and call a query?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I believe this is a code from Oracle Forms, they are all packages I assume, built in or self created, that he uses...

Comment: web_report, pckg_erp, destroy_parameter_list  these are packages used in software

Comment: @WilliamRobertson i want to show report in excel format instead of pdf

Comment: PROCEDURE setDesformat (vDesformat varchar2)IS
  BEGIN
   if (upper(vDesformat) in ('HTML','HTMLCSS','PDF','XML','DELIMITED','RTF','ASCII','PS','PCL','XLS','XLSX','CSV')) then
    rp2rroDesformat := vDesformat;
   else
    message(vDesformat ||'is not a valid desformat');
   end if;
  END; PROCEDURE FOR DESTINATION FORMAT

Comment: I'm pretty much sure that this is misspelled: ENHANSEDSPREADSHEET. Shouldn't that be ENHAN**C**ED ...?

Comment: @MuhammadSaqib I can see they are packages/procedures. I was wondering more what they were doing in your sample code, since we can’t see them. Are they not working?

Comment: @Littlefoot yes ENHANCED was misspelled but still not working i have corrected the mistake